# Activated theme not working in wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, wordpress.com

Every time i activate a theme, its not like it was in demo, no images, no structure. Kindly guide me. This is link of my site https://ranawaleedblog.wordpress.com. And this is link of theme i have activated. https://gazettedemo.wordpress.com/ . You can see the difference. Plz tell me what to do.
Note. I am not using wordpress.org. I m working on wordpress.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its k :) just see this 
https://docs.woothemes.com/document/gazette/

Setting up the home page featured post carousel
↑ Back to Top

If you wish to use the Gazette home page featured carousel you need to enable it in the theme option’s panel. See screenshot below:
gazette-carousel
You then need to assign a category to it to display posts from. For the demo we created a category called “Featured” then assigned some posts to it. You can then specify exactly how many featured entries you want the scroller to scroll through.

Comment: i have already seen this. this is'nt helping me coz i cannot find home page carousel.

Comment: k just create featured category and add new post with this category .

Answer (score 0):

You should Import demo data in your theme.

Comment: Dear check your theme files there would be a demo or sample data file

Comment: There is just a button "activate". No other option.

Comment: check setteing button or try to add some post, demo or sample data normaly comes with theme files , you need to check your download folder

Comment: also some theme has page builder options. you just check setting tab with theme options. and there should be an option in post or category featured-content.

Comment: i did'nt download any file, i just activated it.

Comment: https://theme.wordpress.com/themes/gazette/ check this link also you have to add post or set your home page or you need to find gazette theme documentation.

Comment: Your theme is active you just need rnd how to set home page with post

Comment: Thanks man...its working now. Not exactly bt somewhat. Take a look https://ranawaleedblog.wordpress.com/. Each post has a gap from other, but in demo there is a beautiful style that is not implementing. Anyhow thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you wish to use the Gazette home page featured carousel you need to enable it in the theme option’s panel. See screenshot below: